# React native toLocaleDateString behaves differently on Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I'm trying to format a date string in react native, it works on iOS but display differently on Android, I want to format the date to look like `10 Aug 2018` with short month name, on Android it is displayed as `10/8/18`. I'm using `.toLocaleDateString()` function to format the date but it seems it doesn't work on Android.

```
formatDateStringForDisplay = (dateString) => {

  return dateString && Date.parse(dateString)
    ? new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(
      'en-GB',
      {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric'
      })
    : '';
}
```

This function returns the `10 Aug 2018` on iOS and `10/8/2018` on Android.

I have also tried the following and it works in iOS only.

```
formatDateStringForDisplay = (dateString) => {

  if (!dateString || !Date.parse(dateString)) {
    return '';
  }

  return [
    date.getDate(),
    date.toLocaleDateString(
      'en-GB',
      {
        month: 'short'
      }
    ),
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join(' ');
}
```

This displays `10 Aug 2018` on iOS and `10 10/8/18 2018` on Android, How can I format date in `11 Dec 2018` format? with a short name for a month.

Answer (score 0):

`toLocaleDateString` is NOT a reliable way of getting the format you want. Instead, do this:

```
    var dateobj = new Date();
    function pad(n) {
       return n < 10 ? "0"+n : n;
    }
    var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var result = pad(dateobj.getDate())+" "+ month[dateobj.getMonth()] +" "+dateobj.getFullYear();
```

Also according to the Mozilla documentation, the format can vary wildly depending on the user's location and computer settings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: I want the format of the date to be `10 Aug 2010` not `10/8/2018`

Comment: @julekgwa OK, I changed this to that you want

Comment: "Also according to the Mozilla documentation, the format can vary wildly depending on the user's location and computer settings."  Yes, I would say that is pretty much the point when trying to use `.toLocaleDateString()`